# How do I filter objects in a multidimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have the below data that I wish to filter by the exercise. So for example get all squats across all dates.

[image]

I have tried mapping the workouts value but get errors in Vue using the following code.

```
     this.workouts.map((y) => {
       return console.log(y);
     })
```

> Uncaught TypeError: this.workouts.map is not a function

I have also tried using a for loop but am having issue because the keys are not integers.

```
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < w.length; i++)
    {
      console.log(w[i]);
        if (w[i] == '22-1-2018')
        {
            result.push(w[i]);
        }
    }
```

I almost just need to skip the first two levels.

The result would be an array of objects. Each object would be filtered to squat but also detail the reps, sets and weight.

Comment: What should the result be? Can you post an example of what you want to get back using the data you posted?

Comment: I have updated @CRice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over an object properties with `Object.keys`

```
let filtred;
let wanted = "Squad"
Object.keys(workouts).forEach((date) => {
  filtred[date] = {};
  Object.keys(workouts[date]).forEach((bodypart) => {
   workouts[date][bodypart].forEach((workout) => {
    filtred[date][bodypart] = [];
    if(workout.excercise == wanted){
      filtred[date][bodypart].push(workout)
    }        
   })  
  })
});

console.log(filtred); //here your new array
```

also if you want to include more workouts in the filter you can use an array:

```
let wanted = ["Squad", "Deadlift", "AnotherOne"];
//...te same
// if(workout == wanted){ replacing this
if(wanted.indexOf(workout.exercise) !== -1){
```

as you can see is an O(n^3) complexity, so you should not use this filter with large amounts of data, if you need it then you should change your structure for something more plain, will cost you more memory but the filter will be faster with high amounts of data, something like this:

```
let workouts = [
{
  date: '22-01-2018'
  bodypart: 'legs',
  workout: 'sqad',
  reps: 6,
  sets: 46,
  weight: 60
},
{
  date: '22-01-2018'
  bodypart: 'legs',
  workout: 'Deadlift',
  reps: 6,
  sets: 46,
  weight: 60
},
];
```

this way you can filter it faster with:

```
let filtred = workouts.filter((w) => w.workout == 'sqad');
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `this.workouts` is not an array. It is an object.

If you want to iterate through your `legs` property,you should use the following:

```
this.workouts["22-1-2018"].legs.map(y=>{
    console.log(y)
    return y.exercise;
})
```

If you want to iterate through `keys` aka the dates of the object, you have to use `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(this.workouts)
    .map(keys => {
        console.log(keys)//this should give you "22-1-2018"
        return this.workouts[keys].map(y => {
            return y.legs.map(z => {
                return z.exercise;
            })
        })
    })
```

But what you required is to flattened your Object structure and get a list of `legs` , of which it has to be filtered if its `exercise === 'Squat'`. To do that, you will need to use `.reduce()`:

```
Object.keys(this.workouts)
    .reduce((accumulator, keys) => {
        var item = this.workouts[keys].legs.map(y => y)
            .filter(z => z.exercise === 'Squat');
        return accumulator.concat(item);
    },[])
```

Here is a [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/bolonux/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

But once you've filtered out your exercises, how would you know which date and bodypart it belongs to? So we have to transform and flatten it first, then filter

```
const flatten = data => {
    const result = [];

    Object.keys(workouts).forEach(date =>
        Object.keys(workouts[date]).forEach(
            bodyPart => workouts[date][bodyPart].forEach(
                exercise => result.push({ ...exercise, date, bodyPart });
            )
        )
    )

    return result;
}

const result = flatten(data).filter(v => v.exercise === 'Squat');
```

Answer (score 0):

They key problem here is you are trying to loop over an object.
`map()` is for array only. Array is some kind of obj but obj is not an array. You might misunderstand your datastructure.

To loop over obj, there are many option:

- Just use pure JS loop: There so many option to loop over obj, plz take an investigation and choose the best fit for you.
- Using an existing lib such as Lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues
- You create new prototype `map()` for Object, that extend your JS Object so that you can call `workouts.map(...)`